# move let's encypt to a new server

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a website in the server A and I want to move it to server B, I know I can move the certs or simply issue a new one, my question is, is there a way to do this without downtime? I prefer to issue a new one but in this case I need to change the dns to point the new server but since that moment the website will be untrusted, once the dns is propagated I can issue the new cert and everything else but there will be like 1 minutes where website will be down...

My server is working with docker, each website is a container and when I need to create/renew a cert I'll spin up a container with certbot....any suggestions?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Leave the original server running.

Step 2: Build a new server. Copy the certificates from the old server and install/setup on the new server. Duplicate content, database connections, etc.  Verify that the new server is working.

Step 3: Leave the old server running. Edit your DNS settings to point to the new server.

Step 4: About a week later, decommission the old server. The old server will continue to serve traffic for cached DNS entries until the old DNS Resource Records TTL expire.

These steps should minimize downtime provided that you build the new server correctly.

Note: You will want your web server running on the new server to serve your SSL certificate as the default. That way you can use a tool like `openssl` to verify that your SSL certificate is being used for connections using just the IP address. Disable redirects that send the IP address to the domain name temporarily.